# Oscilloscope preamp for smartphones

Tags: oscilloscope

I want to build an oscilloscope preamp and wonder what sort of op amp should I use? What's the maximum input level a smartphone can handle and should I bias the signal (for instance -5V/+5v to something like 0-1V)? What means of circuit protection should I use? Can I use diodes?

Comment: At the very least you should current limit the signal. If you have a high impedance scope, buy a wired headset and probe on the microphone line to see what kind of voltages you get. Neat project!

Comment: Which input of the smartphone do you intend to use?

Comment: Uh, sorry me, the mic input. I guess it would have a voltage divider, some sort of range selector, an op amp buffer and some circuit protection measures. I wonder which op amp would suit this project?

Comment: There is insurance too: cell phone replacement plan from wireless carrier. :)

Comment: Check also here for variable gain and dual channel: http://www.marzocchi.net/Olafsen/Hardware/Oscilloscopio?setview=en

Answer (score 2):

The microphone input will be sensitive to signals of millivolts, and definitely should be limited to 1V or less. It will probably be AC coupled internally.

See http://www.instructables.com/id/A-Preamplifier-for-Smartphone-Oscilloscopes/
and http://hackaday.com/2012/07/14/android-oscilloscope-built-from-parts-just-laying-around/ ; the latter of those is just an attenuator, relying on the built-in preamp. The former adds a unity gain buffer as an impedance converter, and will probably produce better results. In both cases it's only suitable for audio frequency ranges.

Comment: I've seen both and I'll go for the buffered one. I fonder though if I can use a generic op amp?

Comment: You need one that's stable at unity gain (not all are, e.g. LM386)

Comment: Check the special op-amps called "instrumentation amplifiers" or in-amps. They have high impedance and differential inputs and use a single external resistor to select gain which you can switch for range. Check the application notes for very low cost http://www.jameco.com/Jameco/Products/ProdDS/825934.pdf  I prefer a little more, like AD620  http://www.jameco.com/Jameco/Products/ProdDS/1780862.pdf or go all out with precision single supply  http://www.jameco.com/Jameco/Products/ProdDS/1729936.pdf (Not pushing JameCo. They have easy to find data sheets).